# Populate Core Data structure for iPhone/iPad with Sqlite3

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I have a SQLite database. Should I put the DB in a data structure with Core Data. How can I do? My problem is "z relations" between tables.

It's possible?

Comment: i suggest you convert your sqlite database to a JSON file and import it into core data, if possible.  makes it much easier and you will probably be more successful with the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In the future, should I use SQLite directly, but for those who have a similar problem to mine this solution works well.

Step 1: Core Data in your table add column headed gl'ID temporary relations of the original table.

Step 2: In the data in CSV add two columns. The first column contains the value 1 and refers to P_OPT of Core Data and the second column contains the identifier of the table and retrieved P_ENT generated by reading the SQLite Core Data in the table Z_PRIMARYKEY.

Step 3: With any editor Mac transfer your data in SQLite files generated by Core Data. Remember to attach gl'ID (relations) in the temporary columns.

Step 4: Through the use of the SQL UPDATE command (works with any SQL editor on the Mac) updates all ID columns of relations in Core Data with the value Z_PK. The value retrieved by the queries and the use of temporary columns.

Sorry for the bad English. I hope not to have been convoluted with the explanation and useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

Core Data isn't SQL even when it employs an SQLite store. Although it is theoretically possible to convert a standard SQLite file to the schema Core Data uses, that is difficult and risky especially given that Apple doesn't document the schema and can therefore change it without warning. You really need to translate the SQL data into Core Data objects.

The best way is to write a utility app containing you Core Data model. Read in the SQL data with the standard functions and then use that data and relationships to create the appropriate managed objects and object relationships in Core Data.

Usually you have code anyway for creating managed objects, populating attributes and setting relationships. Just use that code but instead of providing the data from the UI or a feed, provide it from the data provided by SQL.